# dataTransfer.getData not working as expected in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to have dynamic design page and user put slider to desired place but this line work not well

```
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
```

This line should give me selected img id but return this value: `user[i].MainPicAddress`.

I dont know why

Here is all code

```
window.onload = function () {
    var self = this;

    var url = "http://localhost:44300/api/Slider";
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", url);

    x.onload = function () {
        var user = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
        var l = user.length;
        var ss = document.getElementById("MainSliderPic");
        var e = 12 / l;

        if (x.status == "200") {
            for (var i = 0; i < l ; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.setAttribute("class", "col-" + e);
                div.setAttribute("id", "div" + i);
                div.setAttribute("ondrop", drop);
                div.setAttribute("ondragover", allowDrop);

                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.setAttribute("src", user[i].MainPicAddress);
                img.setAttribute("class", "col-" + e);
                img.setAttribute("draggable", true);
                img.setAttribute("ondragstart", drag);
                img.setAttribute("id", "drag" + i);



                div.appendChild(img);
                ss.appendChild(div);

            }
        }
    };
    x.send();
    var response = x.responseBody;
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    debugger;
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var x = document.getElementById(data);
    ev.target.appendChild(x);
}
```

Comment: I already declare it x.onload = function () {
        var user = JSON.parse(x.responseText);

Comment: Don't attach events through setAttribute...

Comment: Dear Kaiido do you have sample to how to attach event ?

Comment: [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)